# Registering applications via Microsoft Graph API fails to display them under Enterprise Applications in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

When a new application is registered using Microsoft's Graph API, it doesn't display when "Enterprise Applications" is used as the application type.

[image]

The only way to get these applications to show up is if I change the application type to "All Applications".

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on here and provide a solution?

These applications are non-Microsoft applications so they should be showing up as an Enterprise Application.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my lab to register a application using Graph explorer API call.
[image]

The thing I noticed is that when we create the an APP registration using it, has been registered in AD but not appearing in Enterprise Applications as the service principal is not created.

[image]

So after creating the Service Principal from Portal , it is shown in Enterprise application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the managed identity set, these don't show up. The managed identity is created via the CLI when the application is registered.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck, I will check it again as per the above comment and add an update here..

Comment: You can refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals . You have created managed identity but I believe you need to create a service principal as well for the application for it to show in Enterprise application.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @AnsumanBal-MT. `az ad sp create --id <registration_app_id> ` is executed immediately following `az ad app create` which is what creates the managed identity in the first place.  Is there another command that I should be using? These commands are executed from a release pipeline, if that's at all worth mentioning.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575490/register-an-application-in-azure-ad-using-the-graph-api or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/494260/register-an-application-on-azure-ad-using-ms-graph.html?sort=oldest

Comment: as you are creating an SP using cli and then registering using graph , the sp may not have permissions configured by the above command that you have mentioned . the above reference on microsoft Q&A might solve your issue .