# Register an Application in Azure AD using the graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to register an application on the azure ad using the Graph API calls.

I am using the postman to hit the APIs and I have admin access in Azure.

So Far I have tried the following things:

1. I registered an application manually on Azure AD using this doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token. (I gave all the required permissions to my application)
2. I am fetching the token using the service to service call client credentials- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow.
3. After getting the token I pass it in the Authorization and hit the MS graph Create Application endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
4. But In the postman, I am not getting any response body. I have checked my Azure Tenant but I am not able to find any newly Registered App.

   For Token service(Get)
   **Endpoint**- [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant-id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bmy-tenant-id%7D/oauth2/token)
   **body**-
   **grant_type**:client_credentials
   **client_id**:{app-id}
   **scope**:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
   client_secret:{secret}
   //resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
   Response success(200) with token

   For Create App(POST)
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
   **body**: {
   "displayName": "Created with MS Graph API"
   }
   Authorization: Bearer {token}
   Response: Nothing is showing in response

[Response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHUCO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, In the API Header, I was specifying the Content-Length= 67 which was not required. Now I am able to get the Success response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If we look at the MS documentation, They have provided the below example

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 67

{
  "displayName": "Display name"
}
```

We don't need to pass the Content-Length in headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the application using the [Create Application API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
```

You need to have enough permissions first to be able to register an application with Azure AD. This sample shows how to register and create an application to target the Graph API. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample