# Create Microsoft Azure AD application programmatically using Node.Js

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We have a requirement where we want to create the Azure AD application automatically for enabling Microsoft Login.

Is there any way we can programmatically achieve the creation part as everywhere it is showing the GUI steps for registering an app in Azure AD.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, use the Graph API

Comment: Can you please give an example or any link to documentation. That will be very helpful. Thanks @HongOoi

Comment: check this discussion and see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575490/register-an-application-in-azure-ad-using-the-graph-api

Comment: I'll have a look at the steps but yeah, seems like this is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can register the application using this api

**`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`**

One of the following permissions is required to call this API

**1)** **Delegated (work or school account):
Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All,
Directory.AccessAsUser.All**

**2)** **Delegated (personal Microsoft account):
Application.ReadWrite.All**

**3)** **Application: Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, Application.ReadWrite.All,
Directory.ReadWrite.All**

Example:

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const application = {
  displayName: 'Display name'
};

await client.api('/applications')
    .version('beta')
    .post(application);
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript)