# How to create Azure App Registration using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure

How can I create an Azure App Registration programmatically using Typescript/Javascript? I have seen some questions asked a few years ago and some mention using the Azure SDK and provide links that are now dead.

I need to create Azure App Registrations and manually setting them up takes a while, I'd like to be able to create them programmatically to automate this process.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to do it using typescript ?

Comment: From my understanding, it needs to work with AWS Cloudformation as a third-party extension. Which is why typescript was requested.

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help with this more than you reading the official API documentation would help you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to achieve the above requirement,

From the official [***Microsoft Documentation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request) we can use the below to create an Application using `javascript`.

> ```
> const options = {
>   authProvider,
> };
>
> const client = Client.init(options);
>
> const application = {
>   displayName: 'Display name'
> };
>
> await client.api('/applications')
>   .post(application);
> ```
>
> For details about how to [**`add the SDK`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) to your project and
> [***create an authProvider***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers) instance, see the [***SDK
> documentation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview).

Alternatively, As suggested by @*Alex Wayne* , We can use the [**`Graph API to create an application`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using below:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Display name"
}
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**| [**Register an Application in Azure AD using the graph API**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575490/register-an-application-in-azure-ad-using-the-graph-api).